# "I've been looking to do [this or that]." Is "looking to do" idiomatic?

Tags: phrases, idioms

Pretty much that's the question. I wanna think that I have heard it used many times ("I've been looking to do that for the longest time"), but now I'm not sure.
Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/51022/14666

Comment: It's idiomatic, not an idiom yet. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/look_6

Comment: Depends which idiom dictionary you choose –  this from the Sterling Dictionary of Idioms: [looking to do something](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=gBp0CLdQbHwC&pg=PA283&lpg=PA283&dq=%22looking+to+do%22+idiom&source=bl&ots=WlqAws22jh&sig=oKaPCuhiFK6DhNqm6EQK2oYrIYo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CNKtUrbuKsWthQf2k4DwBg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22looking%20to%20do%22%20idiom&f=false): [seeking the opportunity to do something – I don't like Kumar's definition]

Comment: It's a simple matter of a particular sense of a verb gaining the complement pattern of its synonyms. This sense of _look_ means 'look forward/intend/plan', and like these predicates, it takes an infinitive complement. E.g, _He's looking/intending/planning to mow the lawn_. _Look forward_, of course, has a connotation of pleasant expectancy, and takes a prepositional phrase (with a gerund) instead of an infinitive: _He's looking forward to mowing the lawn_.

Comment: Good God, I LOVE this website! Thank you so much, Kris, Edwin, and John. This is certainly one of the best places online to find information about the language. Thanks again, everybody!

Answer (score 2):

As John Lawler notes in the comments:

> It's a simple matter of a particular sense of a verb gaining the complement pattern of its synonyms. This sense of *look* means 'look forward/intend/plan', and like these predicates, it takes an infinitive complement. E.g, *He's looking/intending/planning to mow the lawn*. *Look forward*, of course, has a connotation of pleasant expectancy, and takes a prepositional phrase (with a gerund) instead of an infinitive: *He's looking forward to mowing the lawn*.